# How to move a block from content to custom location

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

The block below is added to the bottom of content. I want this block to be called from within the catalog/product/view.phtml. So i can place it with $this->getChildHtml().

```
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_view"     name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom_bundle.phtml" translate="label">
  <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
  <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
  <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone_bundle.phtml"/>
  <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart_bundle.phtml"/>
</block>
```

How to do this ? Do I add a new reference ? like :

```
<reference name="content">
  <reference name="blockname">
    <block></block>
  </reference>
</reference>
```

Comment: Which block are you referring to? name=? or as =?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving existing blocks can be done with the `insert` or `append` actions. Reference the new parent and use the block name as parameter.

## Example

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</reference>
```

But you should know, that this particalar block is already moved in the same way in the default `catalog.xml`. The only reason it is created directly below `content` is that it can be moved to different parents, depending on the product configuration: either `product.info.container1` or `product.info.container2` (both are children of `product.info`)

Comment: how to move default breadcrumbs in product view page to content area..I want to display crumbs above the main image in magento version 1.9